General quadratic in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$
I'm looking to solve the general quadratic equation in $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$, when solutions exist:
$$A\sin^2\theta+B\sin\theta\cos\theta+C\cos^2\theta+D\sin\theta+E\cos\theta+F=0$$
I've found a solution thanks to John Cook here, but it involves converting to a quartic equation in $\sin\theta$, and I'm searching for something less computation-heavy.
My first approach was attempt to re-represent the equation as nested equations that can be solved one-at-a-time, such as
$$u(\theta)=a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta+c, \quad du^2+eu+f=0$$
We can relate the new parameters to the old:
$$\implies d(a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta+c^2+2(ac\sin\theta+bc\cos\theta+ab\sin\theta\cos\theta))+e(a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta+c)+f=0$$
$$\implies a^2d\sin^2\theta+2abd\sin\theta\cos\theta+b^2d\cos^2\theta+2a(cd+e)\sin\theta+2b(cd+e)\cos\theta+(c^2d+ce+f)=0$$
$$\implies A=a^2d,\;B=2abd,\;C=b^2d,\;D=2a(cd+e),\;E=2b(cd+e),\;F=(c^2d+ce+f)$$
The idea was that then we invert these relations to find $a$-$f$ in terms of $A$-$F$, find solutions for $u$, and then find solutions for $\theta$. However, its seems this system of relations is not invertible, and so this particular re-representation fails (namely, it forces $B^2=4A^2C^2)$. There are no other representations obvious to me, nor other ways to solve the equation short of Cook's solution.

This is exactly as difficult as solving a quartic because of the tangent half-angle substitution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

@QiaochuYuan If I understand, solving any degree $n$ polynomial in trigonometric functions is equivalent to solving some degree $2n$ polynomial in the ordinary variable $x$, via this substitution?

Yes, that's right.

This is just a sketch of a solution, as some details must be worked out, and it may not necessarily be easier than solving a quartic equation. Write $x = \cos \theta$ and $y = \sin \theta$. Then we are trying to find solutions of $f(x,y) := Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$ on the circle $g(x,y) := x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$.
Now, instead of solving $f(x,y) = 0$ we may instead solve $f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) = 0$; this will give the same solutions given the constraint $g(x,y) = 0$. Idea: choose $\lambda$ such that $f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) = 0$ defines a degenerate conic. This will be the case precisely when
$$ \det \begin{bmatrix} A-\lambda & B/2 & D/2 \\ B/2 & C-\lambda & E/2 \\ D/2 & E/2 & F + \lambda\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$
This is a cubic equation with real coefficients, so it has a real solution which could be found numerically. (We have no particular need for $\lambda$ to be real, however.) Note: when there are 4 intersection points, this has 3 solutions, corresponding to the 3 ways to choose a pair of lines through them.
So the problem is reduced to the case of a degenerate conic $f'(x,y) := f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y) = 0$, i.e. the conic is (in general) a union of two lines. In other words, $f'(x,y)$ is a product of two linear factors; each factor gives the equation of a line, and the intersection points of each line with the circle together give you the intersection points of the conic and the circle. (How to find the factors is a detail I omit.)
Finally, from the coordinates $(x,y)$ of the solutions you can recover the angle $\theta$.
...As I write this, I realize this is essentially the procedure outlined here.

Amazing! When you say "when there are 4 intersection points...", do you refer to intersection points of $f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$? Is this the only time that we have 3 solutions for $\lambda$?

Sure, but they are the same as the intersection points of the original conic $f(x,y)=0$ with $g(x,y)=0$. Also, the "when" is only because we are talking about real numbers - if we allowed complex solutions, there would always be 4 points (with multiplicity, as tangent points count as multiple).

Makes sense. Thanks!

When you say $f(x,y)$ is a product of two linear factors, you mean $f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y)$, right?

Yeah, in that paragraph I assumed $f(x,y)=0$ is degenerate (since I reduced the problem to the intersection of a degenerate conic with the circle), i.e. the "new" $f$ is $f - \lambda g$ from the original problem. But it does seem clearer to keep $f$ consistent, so hopefully the edit helps. Thanks.
